# unable to update query on insert duplicate entry in PDO

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

Hi have table approvers like below,

By default PENDING is inserted when new requested is created

i want to update the status to PENDING when matching request_id and matched_pattern_id are matched

here is my mysql pdo query.

```
    INSERT  INTO netsuite_sample_request_sku_approvals 
(request_id, matched_pattern_id, approval_status) 
VALUES (:request_id, :matched_pattern_id, :approval_status) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE request_id=:request_id, matched_pattern_id=:matched_pattern_id, 
approval_status=:approval_status
```

The query always insert new record instead of update query. Please help me

[image]

Comment: And do you have a question or what?

Comment: Hi @u_mulder, the query alway run insert instead of update when request_id and matched_patter_id are match

Comment: It doesn't look like request_id and matched_pattern_id are a unique key (1 and 3 match), so you're going to have to create a query to update approval_status where request_id and matched_pattern_id match your variables.